# After hosting Asp.net website the ASPNETDB.MDF can not generate automatecally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, app-data

I am working on ASP.net project. I have made my main database using `sql server`. and I have also used `ASPNETDB.MDF` database as auto generate database. At localhost the whole project run perfectly and the `ASPNETDB.MDF` is also generate automatically.

But after hosting the website, the `ASPNETDB.MDF` didn't generate automatically. I have checked all the things regarding version of `.NET` but all things are perfect. Even the connection with `sql server` is also established perfectly. Just the main issue is related to `ASPNETDB.MDF` which didn't generate automatically on server and shows below error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. **(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

Please anybody help me. I try lots of ways but I didn't get any solutions from that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you hosting this project. Godaddy or your private server?

Comment: I don't think so you can create dynamic database on godaddy. You need to specify location for the database. I don't think so godaddy gives functionality to use location directly with full permission

Comment: @ Arvaan Thanks you. Can you give me some suggestions for this because I can't change the server and I have to use ASPNETDB.MDF.

Comment: Can you add database manually? still I am not sure about dynamic database adding. There might be a way which I don't know

Comment: I had host website using FTP and also host App_Data folder which contain  ASPNETDB.MDF which is generate automatically at localhost.

Comment: so you have database already in your app_data when you host. I am right?

Comment: Yes. But that is auto generated on localhost.

Comment: Can anybody help me? Its urgent requirement for me.

Comment: Can I show your connection string?

Comment: yes. My connection string ==Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx . But this is my sql database connection string. The actual problem is about the ASPNETDB.MDF which is autogenerate.

Comment: let me check on my server

Comment: how to solve this issue. Can anybody give me some way

Comment: My problem is to use both the database which are sql server and ASPNETDB.MDF . On the server the data are successfully bind from sql server database but I am using ASPNETDB.MDF for the add to cart functionality. This ASPNETDB.MDF will generate automatically on localhost. and the project had also run perfectly. But on server the ASPNETDB.MDF can't generate. Please give me some suggestions.